# Sharepoint calculated column, extract month and year from date then increment month

Tags: sharepoint

Hello I need to create a calculated column in SharePoint that extracts the month and the year from a date column then increments the month by 1 month and if original date is in December it would increment month and year.

I tried using  a combo of edate and the text(cell, "MMMM-YYYY") but I cannot increment by one month.  I am wondering how I could do this in a single calculated column?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below formula would work for you:

```
=TEXT(Date(YEAR([Date]),MONTH([Date])+1,DAY([Date])),"MMMM-YYYY")
```

[image]